# Unknown by none, Doubted by a flat few

Tags: riddle

Broaden me, to you improve ones self

Exploration is looking for me, you'll find

Very few once dared to try

Mere Miles Apart we shall never meet

But nowadays few pay me much mind

Along the way new discoveries made... but I ask you, what am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Incomplete answer: Are you

> horizon?

Because

> 1) "broaden one's horizons" means improving oneself 
>  2) New Horizons is an interplanetary space probe, which was launched ("very few once dared to try") back in 2006, but it's currently little news about it ("but nowadays few pay me much mind along the way new discoveries made")
>  3) The visible horizon line is usually several miles away but cannot be reached ("mere miles apart, we shall never meet")
>  4) Bonus: "Doubted by a flat few" - is it about flat Earth theory supporters?

Comment: You got it, i'll be honest i hoped it would take longer than that. and yes you got the flat earth Joke. there is still a hint missing...

Comment: @BladeWraith Make sure you click the checkmark by the answer to mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2):

Are you...

> Earth?

Unknown by none, doubted by a flat few:

> The  Earth is very well known, and it's roundness has been doubted by flat-earthers.

Broaden me, to improve ones self.

> ?

Exploration is looking for me, you'll find.

> People who explore the Earth find new parts of the Earth.

Very few once dared to try,

> Possibly relating to people who have seen Earth from space.

Mere miles apart, we shall never meet.

> No idea. Maybe something to do with "Miles Apart" by Maduk?

But nowadays few pay me much mind.

> The Earth is worsening every day with climate change and pollution, but most people don't seem to care.

Along the way new discoveries made.

> Links back in to the first line and explorers.

Comment: not quite, Trolley813 got it, but not all the clues quite right, althoughi some of your clue answers were very very good

Comment: Ok. I thought their answer was better anyway.